# How to get access to different models in the template?

Tags: django, django-views

I have 3 models

Do I need to change connections in the models, and make the key field not an id, but a name?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Motobike(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And tests:

```
def test_category(setup):
    client = Client()
    category_id = Category.objects.get(name='Мотоциклы').id
    response = client.get(f'/categories/{category_id}/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    response_data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    assert len(response_data) == 2
    assert response_data[1]['name'] == 'Ninja Turbo'
    assert response_data[1]['vendor'] == 'Kawasaki'
    assert response_data[1]['category'] == 'Мотоциклы'
    assert response_data[1]['description'] == ''

    response = client.get(f'/categories/25/')
    assert response.status_code == 404
```

In view I do so:

```
 class CategoryView(DetailView):
     model = Category
     template_name = 'bikes_site/categories_detail.html'

     def get_context_data(self, id, **kwargs):
        context = get_object_or_404(self.model, id)
        context['motobikes'] =   Motobike.objects.filter(category_id=id).all()
    return context
```

I get an error:

> `get_context_data()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Answer (score 1):

The function signature for `get_context_data` is wrong it should be

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    //todo
```

your detail view should like this

```
 class CategoryView(DetailView):
     model = Category
     template_name = 'bikes_site/categories_detail.html'
     pk_url_kwarg = "id"

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) 
       category = self.get_object()
       context['motobikes'] =   Motobike.objects.filter(category_id=category.pk)
       return context
```